# How do I override help_text in django's admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I have multiple admin sites, so different users get a different experience of editing the objects in the database. Each admin site has a different set of objects exposed, and a different styling. All of this can be done by overriding templates and `ModelAdmin` objects.

I can't work out how to provide different `help_text` through the different sites. `help_text` is always taken straight from the model field definition, and there doesn't seem to be a way to override it.

Am I missing something, or is this impossible?

Answer (score 17):

You can create a new model form and override the help_text there:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].help_text = 'New help text!'
```

then use the new form in your ModelAdmin:

```
class MyModel(admin.ModelAdmin):
     ...
     form = MyForm
```

This is the cleaner way to achieve what you want since form fields belong to forms anyway!

Comment: Oddly, this doesn't seem to work with `editable=False` fields. These don't even appear in form.fields...

Comment: Hello @Cerin, yes you're right, read only fields are always excluded from the admin model forms. They are not readonly/disabled form inputs or something like that, it's just the str repr of the model field or method.

Answer (score 12):

An alternative way is to pass `help_texts` keyword to the [`get_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) method like so:

```
def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
    help_texts = {'my_field': 'Field explanation'}
    kwargs.update({'help_texts': help_texts})
    return super().get_form(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `help_texts` keyword gets eventually passed to the [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/models/#modelform-factory) method and rendered as the standard help text from a model in the Django admin.

In case you're using an `InlineModelAdmin`, you need to override [`get_formset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.get_formset) in the same manner.

This also works if you have `readonly_fields` in your ModelAdmin subclass.

Comment: Indeed, I tried the above approaches and this is the only one that works with `readonly_fields`.  The reason is that Django Form objects don't handle the `readonly_fields`, so when you try `self.fields['my_field'].help_text = `, you just get a KeyError.

Comment: This also works for custom fields that do not exist in the model.

Comment: Or `kwargs['help_texts'] = {'my_field': 'Field explanation'}`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/15456158

Answer (score 9):

In Django 1.9, similar to below works for me

```py
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(MyAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['my_field'].help_text = """
    Some helpful text
    """
    return form
```

Comment: This is an useful and quick way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Cerin is right, but his code does not work well (at least with Django 1.4).

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj):
    try:
        field = [f for f in obj._meta.fields if f.name == 'author']
        if len(field) > 0:
            field = field[0]
            field.help_text = 'some special help text'
    except:
        pass
    return self.readonly_fields
```

You will have to change "author" and the `help_text` string to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can always change form field attributes on ModelAdmin constructor, something like:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if siteA:
            help_text = "foo"
        else:
            help_text = "bar"
        self.form.fields["field_name"].help_text = help_text
```

Comment: Doesn't work as far as I can see - ModelAdmin.fields is just a list of strings: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields

Comment: Oops! Actually, fields will be available through the form attribute of ModelAdmin. Also, make sure parent constructor is called first. See edit.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me:
"type object 'ModelForm' has no attribute 'fields'"

Comment: I am getting the same error as well. Did you find a solution to this? I also tried overriding the get_form() method of the ModelAdmin and manipulating the field with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you've defined a custom field in your `admin.py` only, and the field is not in your model, then you can add `help_text` using the `class Meta` of a custom `ModelForm`:

(For example: you want to add a users photo on your form, you can define a custom html `img` tag [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16307554/2645080)).

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # You don't need to define a custom form field or setup __init__()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        help_texts = {"avatar": "User's avatar Image"}


# And tell your admin.py to use the ModelForm:
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SomeModelForm
    
    # ... rest of the code
```

Comment: This approach does not seam to work anymore. I get this error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form OwnerForm needs updating.`

Comment: @ErikKalkoken That's a different error. You can easily add an 'exclude' or 'fields' attribute to your class Meta like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

Answer (score -1):

Try this one (might need to replace self.fields with self.form.fields ...)

```
class PropertyForm(models.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PropertyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for (key, val) in self.fields.iteritems():
            self.fields[key].help_text = 'what_u_want'
```