# python dict.update vs. subscript to add a single key/value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

Every semester I have at least one Python student who uses `dict.update()` to add a single key/value pair, viz.:

```
mydict.update({'newkey':'newvalue'})
```

instead of

```
mydict['newkey'] = 'newvalue'
```

I don't teach this method and I don't know where they're finding examples of this, but I tell them not to do it because it's less efficient (presumably creates a new 2-element dict) and because it's nonstandard. But is that correct?

Honestly, I can understand the desire to use a visible method rather than this syntax - it perhaps feels more consistent with other method calls. But I think it looks like a newbie approach.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you just asking if it is a good/bad idea to use `update` in this way?

Comment: I think that SO is a place to ask *programming* questions -- Not really a place to ask questions about *teaching programming*.  As such, this will likely be closed pretty quickly.  Good luck in your search though.

Comment: yep - and reasons why.  it's not so much a teaching question.  it's a question of whether or not this method inefficient, inadvisable, etc.  the teaching part is just some background.  thanks for the comments

Comment: Wouldn't http://programmers.stackexchange.com probably be a better place?

Comment: what would be the difference then?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: No. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions, which this is (`[]` vs `update`). Programmers.SE explicitly states in its FAQ that it is *not about* "implementation issues or programming tools".

Comment: I don't quite see it as a pure implementation issue, but more like a teaching issue.

Comment: Funny how 7 years later the reasons for closing appear spurious and the question all about programming.

Comment: need to find a way to reopen in a way thw wont be closed again, change tghe question ?? why my teacher teach me to use dict[key] instead of dict.update ??

Comment: @pippo1980 Your edit removed some details ("less efficient", "visible method"), so I rolled it back, but in exchange I wrote a clearer question. You can nominate for reopening if you want; personally I'm on the fence.

Comment: I am around 600 points short of  reopening privileges , I'll be back in a couples of term

Comment: FWIW, cf. `some_list += ['new_element']`. I used to write that when I was a newbie, because that's how you do it in Bash.

Comment: @DavidB. :" Declined - I'm sorry but I don't understand why you are letting moderators know about this. "  --->  If a moderator (a user with a ♦ symbol after their name) closed the question, then you may flag it for moderator attention. Again, do this only after editing and include a detailed explanation of why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions.

Comment: @pippo1980 I'm not sure why you're weighing in now?  This was closed a long time ago, I got my answer, everyone's had their say.  Besides asking a question inappropriate question initially, are you giving me tips on SO etiquette or did I do something else inappropriately?  "why you are letting moderators..." I don't quite know what this is referring to.  thanks

Comment: @DavidB., i tried to reopen the question because I felt that its content could be usefull,   at least was to me. So I reformulate it flagging it.As a response I got " Declined - I'm sorry but I don't understand why you are letting moderators know about this. " by David_B , could be its some-other moderator. I tried to answer David_B question in the comment above. Closed questions looks like depicted as not important or not relevamt or wrong to my eyes, and I suspect to other members too  thats why I tried to reopen it Sorry for asking inappropriate questions, I'll steer clear of SO dont worry

Comment: @pippo1980, I see, well thank you for trying to reopen it.  I understand that it isn't a "how to" question which I guess is why they felt it was inappropriate.  Regardless I found the answers (which got in before they so unceremoniously refused me) to be very helpful, and the discussion was interesting.  

It's a weird coincidence that the moderator should be David_B as well, but it indeed was not me!  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A benchmark shows your suspicions of its performance impact appear to be correct:

```shell
$ python -m timeit -s 'd = {"key": "value"}' 'd["key"] = "value"'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0741 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'd = {"key": "value"}' 'd.update(key="value")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.294 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'd = {"key": "value"}' 'd.update({"key": "value"})'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.461 usec per loop
```

That is, it's about six times slower on my machine. However, Python is already not  a language you'd use if you need top performance, so I'd just recommend use of whatever is most readable in the situation. For many things, that would be the `[]` way, though `update` could be more readable in a situation like this:

```
configuration.update(
    timeout=60,
    host='example.com',
)
```

…or something like that.

Comment: The time taken to perform an indexed update is irrelevant in any meaningful application.  The readability of []= s far more important.  I find the update version far less obvious.

Comment: @PeterWooster: I agree that readability is more important, but I personally find the `update` more readable.

Comment: but you probably never wrote Fortran :)

Comment: @PeterWooster: Very true.

Comment: As I point out in my reply this argument is decades old, with lots of good points on both sides.  The update is more syntactically pure.

Comment: @PeterWooster: That's not why I like the `update` more. I like the `update` more because it doesn't repeat `configuration` on each line and there are less quotes.

Comment: I feel like in cases such as OP's, where you only want to update a single key/value pair, using `[]` makes the most sense, whereas `update` is more natural to use when you want to update your `dict` with items from another `dict` that was already defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 13):

Updating the key directly is thrice as fast, but YMMV:

```
$ python -m timeit 'd={"k":1}; d.update({"k":2})'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.669 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit 'd={"k":1}; d["k"] = 2'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.212 usec per loop
```

Comment: well that sews it up, thanks!  I need to start using timeit

Comment: Just creating `d` takes up a substantial portion of that time. It should be setup instead: `python -m timeit -s 'd={"k":1}' 'd.update({"k":2})'` and `python -m timeit -s 'd={"k":1}' 'd["k"] = 2'`. On Python 3.12, it's about 4.5 times faster vs 2.5 times when `d` is included.

Answer (score 8):

There are people who feel that []= is not a valid syntactic element in an object oriented language, or any other for that matter.  I remember hearing this argument decades ago when  I worked in APL language development.  That syntax is a holdover from Fortran...

I don't personally subscribe to that view and am quite happy with indexed assignment. But there are those that would claim that a real method call is better.  And of course it's always good to have more than one solution.

Edit:
The real issue here is readability, not performance, the indexed assignment has endured because many people find the assignment easier to read even if less theoretically correct.