# Python dictionary keys being separated into characters, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm fairly new to python and I'm getting a problem when trying to declare a dictionary, my code is

```
d = {}
d["hi"] = "1"
```

Which returns

```
{'h':'1', 'i':'1'}
```

Instead of

```
{'hi':'1'}
```

Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're doing something different to what you've posted - because what you expect to happen is what happens.

Comment: This is my exact code from my IDE

Comment: GScale = {}
GScale["hola"] = "Como estas"
print(GScale)

Comment: See https://repl.it/repls/HappygoluckyImmaterialBluefintuna

Comment: And this is the output in the cmd{'h': 'Como estas', 'o': 'Como estas', 'l': 'Como estas', 'a': 'Como estas', 'S'...

Comment: As you can see in my link above - that isn't the case...

Comment: My bad, it is working but somewhere below in the code the dictionary keys get separated at some point, sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `d.update({'hi':'1', 'hola':'2'})` to update multiple keys at once.

When updating a single key its around 3x faster to update the item inplace,
ie:

`d['hi']='1'`

This is explained in here:
[python dict.update vs. subscript to add a single key/value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456158/python-dict-update-vs-subscript-to-add-a-single-key-value-pair)

Comment: `d.update` is not at all the recommend approach for updating a single item in a directory - it's useful for updating a lot of keys at once.

Comment: Recommended by *who*?  For what reason?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, turns out this line was leftover by the previous programmer below my code: GScale = {k:v for kl,v in GScale.items() for k in kl}, which separates every single key into characters