# Taking input for dictionary in python

Tags: python

Can anyone please tell me if it is possible to take the key and value for a dictionary as input in python?
Suppose I have made an empty dictionary. I want to include the key name by taking input from user as well as its corresponding value as well.

Comment: have you tried something? Please post what your have tried.

Comment: You want single value per key.? or mutliple values per key.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple, for each key there is a list of values, note all values will be in string form. You enter the information like this.

Key;

Number of values for that key;

Enter each value seperately

Repeat for each key

Code:

```
def inputDict(numKeys=10):
    #if you want you could make numKeys an input too(numKeys = int(input("Numkeys?")))
    desiredDict = {}
    #ask key and value for the numKeys
    for nameValuePair in range(numKeys):
        key = input("NextKey:\n")
        numVals = int(input("How many values for that key?\n"))
        valList = []
        for value in range(numVals):
            valList.append(input("Next value\n"))
        desiredDict[key] = valList
    return desiredDict
```

Comment: Thanks, This was helpfull. I was looking for similar concept.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to add key and value, you may want to use dict.update() method

Plus, as you wished to add key and value dynamically depending on user's input, get value and key by splitting from user input

User shall input with space in between two values like below

```
key, value = input('input:').split()  #input: Hello 3

my_dict = {}
my_dict.update({key: value})

print(my_dict) #{"Hello" :3}
```

Comment: Add some details, code only answers are likely to be deleted or flagged as low quality.

Comment: Oh my bad I will !

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```py
    n=int(input("enter a number of elements in the dict: "))
    my_dict = {}
    for i in range (n):
      key=input("Enter key :")
      value=input("Enter values :")

      #use either
      my_dict.update({key: value}) # slow way, see link

      #or      
      my_dict[key]=value # fastest way, see link

    print(my_dict)
```

See this link about updating speed of dictionaries:

[python dict.update vs. subscript to add a single key/value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456158/python-dict-update-vs-subscript-to-add-a-single-key-value-pair)

Answer (score 0):

Thw best and simplest way here

```py
n = int(input("Enter the no of entries you want to enter : "))
dict = {}
for i in range(n):
    key = int(input("Enter the key : " ))
    value = input("Enter the value : ")
    dict[key]=value
print(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
places={}
a=int(input("Enter the no. of elements you want to enter"))
for i in range(a):
    k=int(input("Enter the serial number"))
    d=input("Enter the name of the places"))
    places[k]=d
print(places)
```