# Python **kwargs modification in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i try to run below program i get error message in the second loop saying 
second func got multiple values, i expect this program runs in a loop.
my assumption is Kwargs Rude is not getting updated again with the same value.

Qus1: is kwargs.update(animal = "Lion") is right approch to modify value?

Ques2: why i am getting error message?

This below code is just for Learning purpose, No other intention.
any help is appreciated.

**I use Python 3.6**

> Error Message Below Second_Func(variable1,**kwargs,Rude="leone")
>   TypeError: Second_Func() got multiple values for keyword argument
>   'Rude'

```
NiceVar = "Buddy"

def First_Func(variable1,**kwargs):
    for name,value in kwargs.items():
        print("First man",name)
    kwargs.update(animal = "Lion")
    Second_Func(variable1,**kwargs,Rude="leone")

def Second_Func(value1,**kwargs):
    for name,value in kwargs.items():
        print("Second man",value)
    Third_Func(value1,**kwargs,band="martin")

def Third_Func(google,**kwargs):
    for name,value in kwargs.items():
        print("Third man",value)
    print("my Third Function",google)
    First_Func(google,**kwargs)

First_Func(NiceVar,Animal ="man")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

So, a few things here.

1. In python, we tend to reserve TitleCaseNames (like that) for class names, and use only lower case for variables and functions.  That's just convention, but it's one you ought to adopt.
2. If you're just looking to replace a value for a key in a dictionary, then `kwargs['animal'] = 'Lion'` will suffice just fine.  `kwargs` is literally just a dictionary, nothing special.  The `**` just tells the function to lump all extra keyword args into that dict.
3. The problem is that this program is recursive (`Third_Func` calls `First_Func`) again.  So in the first time around, `First_Func` sets the kwarg `Rude` to `"leone"`, and then that gets passed down the line of functions.  Then when it gets back around to `First_Func` again, `kwargs` now contains the key `'Rude'` from the callstack.  You're then trying to pass both the *original* `Rude` kwarg (inside `kwargs`) AND a second copy of `Rude` via a kwarg literal to `Second_Func`.  Python doesn't know what you mean when you've got two values for the name named kwarg, so it crashes like this.

Hope that clarifies the problem!

Example code:

```
def a(**kwargs):
    for key, val in kwargs.items():
        print(key, value)

>>a(arg1=2, **{'arg1': 7})
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a() got multiple values for argument 'arg1'
```

Answer (score 1):

- **Question 1:** yes, `kwargs.update` is one of the right approaches. But according to some observations, a little bit slower than
  assigning. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456158/python-dict-update-vs-subscript-to-add-a-single-key-value-pair).
- **Question 2:** Because from `Third_Func` you're calling `First_Func` again with all kwargs collected previously. Then, when `Second_Func`
  is called with adding `Rude="leone"` again, you are getting this
  error. Pay attention here, at this point `kwargs` already contains a
  key `Rude`, so the duplication appears.

Also note that, even after fixing this, you will get an endless recursion.