# Why do we need a dict.update() method in python instead of just assigning the values to the corresponding keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been working with dictionaries that I have to modify within different parts of my code. I am trying to make sure if I do not miss anything about there is no need for dict_update() in any scenario.

So the reasons to use update() method is either to add a new key-value pair to current dictionary, or update the value of your existing ones.

But wait!?

Aren't they already possible by just doing:

```
>>>test_dict = {'1':11,'2':1445}
>>>test_dict['1'] = 645
>>>test_dict
{'1': 645, '2': 1445}
>>>test_dict[5]=123
>>>test_dict
{'1': 645, '2': 1445, 5: 123}
```

In what case it would be crucial to use it ? I am curious.

Many thanks

Comment: Update can set multiple keys at once, optionally from another dict.

Comment: Sure they are possible one at a time. With update you can update 50 keys/values at once.

Comment: Ah, okay I just got it. "at once" is the difference.

Comment: Related: [python dict.update vs. subscript to add a single key/value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456158/python-dict-update-vs-subscript-to-add-a-single-key-value-pair)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### 1. You can update many keys on the same statement.

```
my_dict.update(other_dict)
```

In this case you don't have to know how many keys are in the `other_dict`. You'll just be sure that all of them will be updated on `my_dict`.

#### 2. You can use any iterable of key/value pairs with dict.update

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) you can use another dictionary, kwargs, list of tuples, or even generators that yield tuples of len 2.

#### 3. You can use the `update` method as an argument for functions that expect a function argument.

Example:

```
def update_value(key, value, update_function):
    update_function([(key, value)])

update_value("k", 3, update_on_the_db)  # suppose you have a update_on_the_db function
update_value("k", 3, my_dict.update)  # this will update on the dict
```

Answer (score 12):

`d.update(n)` is basically an efficient implementation of the loop

```
for key, value in n.items():
    d[key] = value
```

But syntactically, it also lets you specify explicit key-value pairs without building a `dict`, either using keyword argumetns

```
d.update(a=1, b=2)
```

or an iterable of pairs:

```
d.update([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldnot realize it because I used it already within the loops. It makes total sense now. Thanks