# How do I update a dictionary where the key is a variable?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I am trying to update a dictionary using dict.update() where the key name is a variable, like so:

```
Dict = {}
Var1 = 1
Var2 = 2

Dict.update(Var1=Var2)
print(Dict)
```

However, this outputs:

> {'Var1': 2}

Instead of what I need, which is:

> {1:2}

This is not my code just a similar example, but is there any way to make it read the variable as a variable instead of as a string?

Comment: no, this is not a good example. you technicall dont need the `dct.update` and can instead just do `D = {V1: V2}` which voids the need to use update at all.

Comment: @rv.kvetch - This is an ideal example. Exactly what we want to see here on SO. OP bumps into a problem and writes a small example to demonstrate just the issue at hand. Its easy to see the confusion. +1 for me.

Comment: I am saying that the example could be interpreted multiple ways. However the simplest that comes to mind for me is, why construct an empty dict and do `Dct[V1] = V2` following the empty dict construction. It just does not add up, and prompts the question of what is the use of update in the case of an empty dict.

Comment: @rv.kvetch - This is a question about `update`, not about how the dictionary was created. OP did the right thing - instead of posting a bunch of irrelevant code, we get the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `update` like this, you are using *keyword arguments*, where you can pass parameters by name instead of by position in the list of arguments. The keyword in such arguments is treated as a name; the only way to have a variable keyword is to use the `**kwargs` syntax to pass an entire dict as a set of key=value parameters. That means that this *would* work . . .

```
update = { Var1: Var2 }
Dict.update(**update)
```

. . . except that keywords have to be strings, not numbers; trying to use your `Var1` with value 1 as a keyword triggers a `TypeError`.

Because `dict.update` is designed for updating a dictionary, however, it also accepts an actual dictionary as an argument, without conversion to keyword arguments via `**`. So this does work:

```
Dict.update({ Var1: Var2 })
```

But you don't need `update` or its keyword arguments in your case; you can just use assignment instead:

```
Dict[Var1] = Var2
```

A couple style things: don't name variables with capital letters; that is usually an indication that a value is a constant. Also, don't use "Dict" as a variable name. Such names risk shadowing builtin functions, since functions and variables share the same namespace in Python. For example, if you assign a value to `dict`, you've just removed your pointer to the `dict` global function.

Comment: On the style things: I know, I was just trying to make it easier to read and understand what I'm trying to do, but thank you

Comment: @KianMurray - I agree. Its a reasonable way to write demo code, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Just this:

```
Dict[var1] = var2
```

Calling "update" is a different thing: it can update several keys at once, and it is more usually called with another dictionary passed as positional parameter. In the form `.update(par_name=value)` the left part is used by the language as a "named parameter" and it is fixed in code, as a literal.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to both existing answers, you could do the following if you'd prefer to use update:

```
Dict.update({Var1: Var2})
```

Comment: But to be clear, its a bad way of doing it.

Comment: Yes, for just a single key-value pair it's excessive. Using the update function makes more sense when wanting to update multiple key-value pairs, or when wanting to update using another dictionary. This link discusses some other use cases that may arise for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773526/why-do-we-need-a-dict-update-method-in-python-instead-of-just-assigning-the-va