# Django Admin Show Image from Imagefield

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, admin

While I can show an uploaded image in list_display is it possible to do this on the per model page (as in the page you get for changing a model)?

A quick sample model would be:

```
Class Model1(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=directory)
```

The default admin shows the url of the uploaded image but not the image itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 110, accepted):

In addition to the answer of Michael C. O'Connor

Note that since Django v.1.9 (updated - tested and worked all the way to Django 3.0)

```
image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

is deprecated and [you should use format_html(), format_html_join(), or mark_safe() instead](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)

So if you are storing your uploaded files in your public /directory folder, your code should look like this:

```
from django.utils.html import mark_safe


    Class Model1(models.Model):
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=directory)

        def image_tag(self):
            return mark_safe('<img src="/directory/%s" width="150" height="150" />' % (self.image))

        image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

and in your admin.py add:

```
fields = ['image_tag']
readonly_fields = ['image_tag']
```

Comment: Why include "fields = ( 'image_tag', )"? From testing that removes all other fields from being shown when viewing the model with the image. If you leave that out it just appends the new field to the bottom of the form. I also don't understand the obsession with trailing commas but I'm just being nit picky about that aspect.

Comment: Apparently, fields = ('image_tag', ) is needed only if you specify all the other fields that you want. For example, if you have a model with 20 attributes, but you don't want to visualize all of them, you can specify in such way only those that you want to.

The obsession with the commas is just to avoid missing one if you add something else after. It has been used in many tutorials and books related to Django, in any case, it is not necessarily needed. I, personally, find it useful.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some side effect with the fields variable for certain version of Django or python. That makes more sense.

Comment: @Sensei and palamunder, actually there is a difference regarding the trailing commas - they _are_ required when a tuple has only a single object, or it's not treated as a tuple. Try `foo = ('a'); bar = ('b',); print foo, bar`, and you'll see the difference. I'm actually surprised that Django example works with a non-collection object, but then Django does a lot of things well.

Comment: mark_safe works for me. It's important to specify where come from (from django.utils.html import mark_safe)

Comment: I doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 139):

Sure.  In your model class add a method like:

```
def image_tag(self):
    from django.utils.html import escape
    return u'<img src="%s" />' % escape(<URL to the image>)
image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

and in your `admin.py` add:

```
fields = ( 'image_tag', )
readonly_fields = ('image_tag',)
```

to your `ModelAdmin`.  If you want to restrict the ability to edit the image field, be sure to add it to the `exclude` attribute.

Note: With Django 1.8 and 'image_tag' only in readonly_fields it did not display.  With 'image_tag' only in fields, it gave an error of unknown field.  You need it both in fields and in readonly_fields in order to display correctly.

Comment: heyy, was trying out the solution metioned but the image still doesn't appear, what I can see is the image url... Can somebody help?

Comment: @Anuradha, did you include the `image_tag.allow_tags = True` bit?  Otherwise, the tags will be escaped and the full `<img ...>` tag will be displayed.  You should probably ask this in a separate question though.

Comment: @MichaelC.O'Connor, yes its working now. Had added image_tag.allow_tags = True at wrong place

Comment: For newer versions of Django (1.9+) see the answer by @palamunder

Comment: deprecated in Django v.1.9, @palamunder has answered this.

Answer (score 69):

> It can be done in admin without modifying model

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(Model1) 
class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def image_tag(self, obj):
        return format_html('<img src="{}" />'.format(obj.image.url))

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'

    list_display = ['image_tag',]
```

Comment: This is only for the list view, not the actual model change form

Comment: How would help text be added onto this?

Comment: Thanks! a couple of improvements and complementations: '<img src="{}"width="150" height="150" />' for custom image size. Use @admin.register(Model1) annotation over  Model1Admin class instead of admin.site.register(Model1, Model1Admin) line for a little cleaner code

Comment: You're kinda missing the point of `format_html` by doing the actual formatting yourself. Those arguments passed to str.format should be passed instead to the `format_html` function

Answer (score 20):

**For Django 1.9**
To show image instead of the file path in edit pages, using ImageWidget is nice way to do it.

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.contrib import admin


class AdminImageWidget(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        output = []
        if value and getattr(value, "url", None):
            image_url = value.url
            file_name = str(value)
            output.append(u' <a href="%s" target="_blank"><img src="%s" alt="%s" /></a> %s ' % \
                          (image_url, image_url, file_name, _('Change:')))
        output.append(super(AdminFileWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs))
        return mark_safe(u''.join(output))


class ImageWidgetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    image_fields = []

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name in self.image_fields:
            request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
            kwargs['widget'] = AdminImageWidget
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(ImageWidgetAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

**Usage:**

```
class IndividualBirdAdmin(ImageWidgetAdmin):
    image_fields = ['thumbNail', 'detailImage']
```

Images will show up for the fields, `thumbNail` and `detailImage`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. One question: Why do you pop request from kwargs?

Comment: Ah. Figured it out myself. `db_field.formfield()` method does not expect a request kwarg and will throw.

Comment: Subclassing AdminFileWidget does seem to me as the more elegant solution, thanks.

Comment: This works until Django 2.1 break it.  Please see updated code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51952895/3731039)

Comment: Even better to just simply use [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) instead of `ImageWidgetAdmin `. It's the same effectively

Answer (score 16):

With [django-imagekit](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit) you can add any image like this:

```
from imagekit.admin import AdminThumbnail

@register(Fancy)
class FancyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'image_display']
    image_display = AdminThumbnail(image_field='image')
    image_display.short_description = 'Image'

    readonly_fields = ['image_display']  # this is for the change form
```

Comment: Two birds with one stone. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This only changes the list display, and not the display of the image in the admin change form.

Comment: This was the fastest way, I was able to show pics in changeform and list view.

Answer (score 11):

While there are some good, functional solutions already shared here, I feel that non-form markup, such as auxiliary image tags, belong in templates, not tacked on to Django form widgets or generated in model admin classes. A more semantic solution is:

## Admin Template Overrides

**Note:** Apparently my reputation isn't high enough to post more than two simple links, so I have created annotations in the following text and included the respective URLs at the bottom of this answer.

From the [Django Admin Site documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates):

> It is relatively easy to override many of the templates which the admin module uses to generate the various pages of an admin site. You can even override a few of these templates for a specific app, or a specific model.

Django's `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin` (commonly accessed under the namespace `django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin`) presents a series of possible template paths to [Django's template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render) in order from most specific to less so. This snippet was copied directly from `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.render_change_form`:

```py
return TemplateResponse(request, form_template or [
    "admin/%s/%s/change_form.html" % (app_label, opts.model_name),
    "admin/%s/change_form.html" % app_label,
    "admin/change_form.html"
], context)
```

Therefore, considering the aforementioned Django admin template override documentation and the template search paths, suppose one has created an app "articles" in which is defined a model class "Article". If one wants to override or extend *only* the default Django admin site change form for model `articles.models.Article`, one would execute the following steps:

1. Create a template directory structure for the override file.

   - Although the documentation does not mention it, the template loader will look in app directories first if `APP_DIRS`<sup>1</sup> is set to `True`.
   - Because one wants to override the Django admin site template by app label and by model, the resulting directory hierarchy would be: `<project_root>/articles/templates/admin/articles/article/`
2. Create the template file(s) in one's new directory structure.

   - Only the admin change form needs to be overridden so create `change_form.html`.
   - The final, absolute path will be `<project_root>/articles/templates/admin/articles/article/change_form.html`
3. Completely override or simply extend the default admin change form template.

   - I wasn't able to locate any information in the Django documentation concerning the context data available to the default admin site templates so I was forced to look at the Django source code.

     - Default change form template: github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html
     - A few of the relevant context dictionary definitions can be found in
       `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin._changeform_view` and `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin.render_change_form`

### My Solution

Assuming that my ImageField attribute name on the model is "file", my template override to implement image previews would be similar to this:

```html
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block field_sets %}
{% if original %}
<div class="aligned form-row">
    <div>
        <label>Preview:</label>
        <img
            alt="image preview"
            src="/{{ original.file.url }}"
            style="max-height: 300px;">
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% for fieldset in adminform %}
  {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

`original` appears to be the model instance from which the ModelForm was generated. As an aside, I usually don't use inline CSS but it wasn't worth a separate file for a single rule.

#### Sources:

1. *docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#app-dirs*

Comment: This post works. I almost copied your code block exactly, except for that I changed the "src" line to: src="{{ original.file.url }}",  note the removal of slash.

Answer (score 8):

I was trying to figure it out myself and this is what i came up with

```
@admin.register(ToDo)
class ToDoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def image_tag(self, obj):
        return format_html('<img src="{}" width="auto" height="200px" />'.format(obj.img.url))

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'

    list_display = ['image_tag']
    readonly_fields = ['image_tag']
```

Comment: That's not how `format_html` is supposed to be used. Read the docs

Answer (score 5):

[This is](http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/imagefield.html) how it worked for django 2.1 without modifying `models.py`:

In your `Hero` model, you have an image field.:

```
headshot = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="hero_headshots/")
```

You can do it like this:

```
@admin.register(Hero)
class HeroAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):

    readonly_fields = [..., "headshot_image"]

    def headshot_image(self, obj):
        return mark_safe('<img src="{url}" width="{width}" height={height} />'.format(
            url = obj.headshot.url,
            width=obj.headshot.width,
            height=obj.headshot.height,
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

Tested on Django v3.2.*

- Just you can write this code in your `model.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.html import mark_safe


class Book(models.Model):
        image = models.ImageField()

        def image_tag(self):
                if self.image != '':
                    return mark_safe('<img src="%s%s" width="150" height="150" />' % (f'{settings.MEDIA_URL}', self.image))
```

- Then add this in `admin.py`

```py
list_display = ['image_tag']
```

Answer (score 3):

Django 2.1 update for Venkat Kotra's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32791358/3731039).  The answer works fine on Django 2.0.7 and below.  But gives server 500 error (if `DEBUG=False`) or gives

`render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'`

The reason is that in Django 2.1: `Support for Widget.render() methods without the renderer argument is removed.`  So, param `renderer` is mandatory now.  We must update function `render()` of `AdminImageWidget` to include param `renderer`.  And it must be after `attrs` (before `kwargs` if you have it):

```
class AdminImageWidget(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        output = []
        if value and getattr(value, "url", None):
            image_url = value.url
            file_name = str(value)
            output.append(u' <a href="%s" target="_blank"><img src="%s" alt="%s" /></a> %s ' % \
                      (image_url, image_url, file_name, _('Change:')))
        output.append(super(AdminFileWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs, renderer))
        return mark_safe(u''.join(output))
```

Comment: is there a way to add on hover css class to the image so the thumbnail in list display gets bigger?

Comment: @Martins I only post a fix which fix the crash on Django 2.1+.  And I don't know hover css, couldn't help. Since your question is, in fact, another question, you may better post it as new question.  This thread is getting old and might not have further discussion (except bug fix like this one).

Answer (score 3):

**Django ver. 3.0.3**

**models.py:**

```
def image_tag(self):
    from django.utils.html import mark_safe
    return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="100px" height="100px" />'%(self.image.url))
image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

**admin.py:**

```
list_display = ('image_tag', )
```

Answer (score 3):

For example, there is **`Product` model** below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    image = models.ImageField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And, there is **`Product` admin** below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Then, an uploaded image is not displayed in **"Change" page** in Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

Now, I override `AdminFileWidget` then assign `CustomAdminFileWidget` to [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.db import models
                            # Here
class CustomAdminFileWidget(AdminFileWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        result = []
        if hasattr(value, "url"):
            result.append(
                f'''<a href="{value.url}" target="_blank">
                      <img 
                        src="{value.url}" alt="{value}" 
                        width="100" height="100"
                        style="object-fit: cover;"
                      />
                    </a>'''
            )
        result.append(super().render(name, value, attrs, renderer))
        return format_html("".join(result))

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {           # Here
        models.ImageField: {"widget": CustomAdminFileWidget}
    }
```

Then, an uploaded image is displayed in **"Change" page** in Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

You can also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443752/how-to-display-uploaded-images-in-change-list-page-in-django-admin/75140612#75140612) explaining how to display uploaded images in **"Change List" page** in Django Admin.

Answer (score 2):

@palamunder's answer worked for me on Django 2.2 with a couple minor changes.

Model.py

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class AdminCategory(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(_("Image"),
            upload_to='categories/',
            blank=True,
            default='placeholder.png')

    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s" width="150" height="150" />' % (
            self.image.url))  # Get Image url

    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
```

Admin.py

```
admin.site.register(
    AdminCategory,
    list_display=["image_tag"],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show image preview before save, you could use custom django template + js

admin.py

```
class UploadedImagePreview(object):
    short_description = _('Thumbnail')
    allow_tags = True

    def __init__(self, image_field, template, short_description=None, width=None, height=None):
        self.image_field = image_field
        self.template = template
        if short_description:
            self.short_description = short_description
        self.width = width or 200
        self.height = height or 200

    def __call__(self, obj):
        try:
            image = getattr(obj, self.image_field)
        except AttributeError:
            raise Exception('The property %s is not defined on %s.' %
                (self.image_field, obj.__class__.__name__))

        template = self.template

        return render_to_string(template, {
            'width': self.width,
            'height': self.height,
            'watch_field_id': 'id_' + self.image_field  # id_<field_name> is default ID 
                                                        # for ImageField input named `<field_name>` (in Django Admin) 
        })


@admin.register(MyModel)
class MainPageBannerAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    image_preview = UploadedImagePreview(image_field='image', template='admin/image_preview.html',
                                         short_description='uploaded image', width=245, height=245)
    readonly_fields = ('image_preview',)
    
    fields = (('image', 'image_preview'), 'title')
```

image_preview.html

```
<img id="preview_{{ watch_field_id }}" style="display: none; width: {{ width }}px; height: {{ height }}px" alt="">

<script>
    function handleFileSelect(event) {
        var files = event.target.files; // FileList object
        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            // Only process image files
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) continue;
            // Init FileReader()
            // See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader
            var reader = new FileReader();
            // Closure to capture the file information
            reader.onload = (function () {
                return function (e) {
                    // Render background image
                    document.getElementById('preview_{{watch_field_id}}').src = e.target.result;
                    // Set `display: block` to preview image container
                    document.getElementById('preview_{{watch_field_id}}').style.display = 'block';
                };
            })(f);
            // Read in the image file as a data URL
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    // Change img src after change file input
    // watch_field_id — is ID for ImageField input
    document.getElementById('{{ watch_field_id }}').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```