# Add `help_text` to Django Admin field

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm attempting to display an image when editing a user on the admin panel, but I can't figure out how to add help text.

I'm using this [Django Admin Show Image from Imagefield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307307/django-admin-show-image-from-imagefield/40715745#40715745) code, which works fine.

However the `short_description` attribute only names the image, and `help_text` doesn't seem to add an text below it.

How can I add `help_text` to this field like normal model fields?

**EDIT:**

I would like to have `help_text` on the image like the password field does in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of admin page]

Answer (score 14):

Use a custom form if you don't want change a model:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].help_text = 'My help text'

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ()

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
    # ...
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add the help text though. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your field in the `MyModel` contain the `help_text` parameter like this: `image = models.ImageField(<...>, help_text='My help text')`?

Comment: I currently just pull the url from the model and I want to avoid adding anything else to it.

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while to figure out. If you've defined a custom field in your `admin.py` only and the field is not in your model. Use a custom ModelForm:

```
class SomeModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # You don't need to define a custom form field or setup __init__()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        help_texts = {'avatar': "User's avatar Image"}
        exclude = ()
```

And in the admin.py:

```
class SomeModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SomeModelForm
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have to define `model` or `exclude` attributes either (just `help_texts`) to make it work with the Admin panel :D

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to create a custom model form class :

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj=obj, change=change, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields["image"].help_text = "Some help text..."
        return form
```