# model method added to fieldsets throws FieldError

Tags: python, django, methods, django-admin

I have added a model method that successfully displays the images in admin, but only in `list_display`, if I add it to a `fieldsets` with the goal of also make it display when editing or adding. It throws an error.

```
Exception Value:    

Unknown field(s) (thumbnail) specified for Image. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ImageAdmin.
```

I'm sure that I am doing something "illegal". Or trying to do something that doesn't make sense. Because if I go and add an image that doesn't exist yet, it can't show the image either.

I am clearly missing how this all tie together. Can someone explain?

Thank you

**In my models.py**

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=_image_upload)

    def thumbnail(self):
        return format_html(
            '<img src="{}" width="auto" height="250">'.format(self.image.url)
        )
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Image)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Edit or upload image', {
            'fields': ('thumbnail','...',) #throws a FieldError
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('thumbnail', '...') #works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `readonly_fields` to `ImageAdmin`:

```
@admin.register(Image)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = 'thumbnail'  # ADD THIS
    fieldsets = (
        ('Edit or upload image', {
            'fields': ('thumbnail','...',) #throws a FieldError
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('thumbnail', '...') #works
```

If you need the thumbnail only for the admin, see [how to use AdminThumbnail from django-imagekit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38718010/621690).

Comment: Thanks @Risadinha your solutions worked beautifully. And the https://github.com/matthewwithanm/django-imagekit looks interesting. Thanks for sharing.