# How to display django category name instead of Category object (1)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

Here is the problem. I've added a category section into my django blog. When I'm trying to add new category, there is a problem with user localization. When I'm adding the category, for example *django*, it shows like this:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSUe0.png)

in the admin panel the same:
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6WKx.png)

but I actually add a normal category name:
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Uou.png)

The funny thing is that, after I posted content with `category` in my web-app, it's looking normally:
[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHKKK.png)

I want something like this, maybe someone have solution: [wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cecdi.png)

Some code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', default="images/None/no-img.jpg")



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView


def home(request):
    content = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', content)

def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__name__contains=category).order_by('-date_posted')
    content = {
        'category': category,
        'posts': posts
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_category.html', content) #<--(didn't add content block) bug found 05.11.19

def upload_pic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            m = ExampleModel.objects.get(pk=course_id)
            m.model_pic = form.cleaned_data['image']
            m.save()
            return HttpResponse('image upload success')
    return HttpResponseForbidden('allowed only via POST')

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'categories', 'image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'categories', 'image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author: #checking if it's trully the same author who has created the post
            return True
        return False
```

**category section**

```
  <div>
          <!-- category section -->
          <small class="text-muted">
            Categories:&nbsp;
            {% for category in post.categories.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'blog_category' category.name %}">
              {{ category.name }}
            </a>&nbsp;
            {% endfor %}
          </small>
        </div>
```

Comment: implementing `__str__` method in python3 you can define how represent your object when is printed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432364/how-to-display-all-my-models-fields-in-django-admin/58432519#58432519

Comment: Thanks for help, guys:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You implement the `__str__` method of the `Category` class:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```