# Image Display in Django

Tags: django

```
ERRORS:
<class 'blog.admin.CategoryAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'image_tag', which is n
ot a callable, an attribute of 'CategoryAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'blog.Category'.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

Comment: models.py
def image_tag(self):
     return format_html(
       '<img src="/media/{}" style="width:40px;height:40px;border-radius:50%;"  />'.format(self.image))

admin.py
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('image_tag', 'title', 'description', 'url', 'add_date',)
    search_fields = ('title',)

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: Please refer this questions [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16307307/django-admin-show-image-from-imagefield)

Answer (score 0):

model.py

```
class Demo(models.Model):
    """ Class for demo Model. """
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='folder_name/', null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class DemoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """ Class for Demo Admin. """
    list_display = ('image_source',)

    def image_source(self):
        return format_html('media/folder_name/{}'.format(self.image))
```