# Is there a way to display all user last_login and date_joined in django

Tags: django

I want to display all users information on admin dashboard with their last_login and join date
I filter user date to display on template

```
    data = Profile.objects.filter(Q(user__is_superuser=False), Q(user__is_staff=False)).order_by('-user__last_login')[:10]
```

Profile model

```
 user = models.OneToOneField(User,default="1", on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name="profile")
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="default/user.png")

 def __str__(self):
   return f'{self.user} profile'
```

I want to do like [image: this]

In the last_login and date_joined column, I want to print all users  last login date time and join date time

Comment: How do you render the table?

Answer (score 1):

try this in admin.py of your app for User Admin

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = UserAdmin.list_display + ("last_login","date_joined")
```

However, if you want to show this information in your Profile Admin you should use this code

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =  ("last_login","date_joined")
    
    def last_login(self, instance):
        return instance.user.last_login
    
    def date_joined(self, instance):
        return instance.user.date_joined
```

Comment: Thanks Armin NaCl for you response, I am using superuser as admin in my project is this solution works for that condition

Comment: how can I display it on template

Comment: Please provide full solution

Comment: yes it works for superusers and you should just open the URL of your Django admin dashboard, for displaying the images field in admin you can Reference this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16307554/19175189)